# Implementing PartialEq on a boxed trait

Tags: rust, traits

I have a Rust program which contains a number of different structs which all implement a trait called `ApplyAction`. Another struct, `ActionList`, contains a vector of boxed objects which implement `ApplyAction`. I would like to create some unit tests which compare `ActionList`s with one another.

There are a few different SO questions which deal with `PartialEq` on boxed traits, and I've used these to get some way towards an implementation. However, in the (simplified) code below (and on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4915eeef286b49634fec8cfe940691f9&version=stable)), the assertions in `main()` fail because the type ids of the objects passed to `eq()` differ. Why?

Also, this seems extremely complicated for such a simple use case -- is there an easier way to do this?

```
use std::any::TypeId;
use std::boxed::Box;
use std::fmt;
use std::mem::transmute;

#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct MyAction<T: fmt::Debug> {
    label: T,
}

impl<T: fmt::Debug> MyAction<T> {
    pub fn new(label: T) -> MyAction<T> {
        MyAction { label: label }
    }
}

pub trait ApplyAction<T: fmt::Debug + PartialEq>: fmt::Debug {
    fn get_type(&self) -> TypeId;
    fn is_eq(&self, other: &ApplyAction<T>) -> bool;
}

impl<T: fmt::Debug + Eq + 'static> ApplyAction<T> for MyAction<T> {
    fn get_type(&self) -> TypeId {
        TypeId::of::<MyAction<T>>()
    }

    fn is_eq(&self, other: &ApplyAction<T>) -> bool {
        if other.get_type() == TypeId::of::<Self>() {
            // Rust thinks that self and other are different types in the calls below.
            let other_ = unsafe { *transmute::<&&ApplyAction<T>, &&Self>(&other) };
            self.label == other_.label
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}

impl<T: fmt::Debug + Eq + PartialEq + 'static> PartialEq for ApplyAction<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &ApplyAction<T>) -> bool {
        if other.get_type() == TypeId::of::<Self>() {
            self.is_eq(other)
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ActionList<T: fmt::Debug> {
    actions: Vec<Box<ApplyAction<T>>>,
}

impl<T: fmt::Debug + PartialEq> ActionList<T> {
    pub fn new() -> ActionList<T> {
        ActionList { actions: vec![] }
    }
    pub fn push<A: ApplyAction<T> + 'static>(&mut self, action: A) {
        self.actions.push(Box::new(action));
    }
}

impl<T: fmt::Debug + Eq + PartialEq + 'static> PartialEq for ActionList<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &ActionList<T>) -> bool {
        for (i, action) in self.actions.iter().enumerate() {
            if **action != *other.actions[i] {
                return false;
            }
        }
        true
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut script1: ActionList<String> = ActionList::new();
    script1.push(MyAction::new("foo".to_string()));
    let mut script2: ActionList<String> = ActionList::new();
    script2.push(MyAction::new("foo".to_string()));
    let mut script3: ActionList<String> = ActionList::new();
    script3.push(MyAction::new("bar".to_string()));
    assert_eq!(script1, script2);
    assert_ne!(script1, script3);
}
```

Comment: You can do something like this: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6d49d7c1c1cc97393328eb18c68cb43d&version=stable). I cannot write full answer now, so feel free to write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `impl<...> PartialEq for ApplyAction<T>` you used `TypeId::of::<Self>()`; i.e. the type of the unsized trait object.  That isn't what you wanted; but remove the `if` and directly call `self.is_eq(other)`, and your code should be working.

Sadly your example requires a lot of code to implement `ApplyAction<T> for MyAction<T>` - and again for each other action type you might want to use.

I tried to remove that overhead, and with nightly features it is completely gone (and otherwise only a small stub remains):

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=64595c2e85bd3877b94af7f37d7c77d6&version=nightly)

```
// see `default impl` below
#![feature(specialization)]

// Any::<T>::downcast_ref only works for special trait objects (`Any` and
// `Any + Send`); having a trait `T` derive from `Any` doesn't allow you to
// coerce ("cast") `&T` into `&Any` (that might change in the future).
//
// Implementing a custom `downcast_ref` which takes any
// `T: Any + ?Sized + 'static` as input leads to another problem: if `T` is a
// trait that didn't inherit `Any` you still can call `downcast_ref`, but it
// won't work (it will use the `TypeId` of the trait object instead of the
// underlying (sized) type).
//
// Use `SizedAny` instead: it's only implemented for sized types by default;
// that prevents the problem above, and we can implement `downcast_ref` without
// worrying.

mod sized_any {
    use std::any::TypeId;

    // don't allow other implementations of `SizedAny`; `SizedAny` must only be
    // implemented for sized types.
    mod seal {
        // it must be a `pub trait`, but not be reachable - hide it in
        // private mod.
        pub trait Seal {}
    }

    pub trait SizedAny: seal::Seal + 'static {
        fn get_type_id(&self) -> TypeId {
            TypeId::of::<Self>()
        }
    }

    impl<T: 'static> seal::Seal for T {}
    impl<T: 'static> SizedAny for T {}

    // `SizedAny + ?Sized` means it can be a trait object, but `SizedAny` was
    // implemented for the underlying sized type.
    pub fn downcast_ref<From, To>(v: &From) -> Option<&To>
    where
        From: SizedAny + ?Sized + 'static,
        To: 'static,
    {
        if TypeId::of::<To>() == <From as SizedAny>::get_type_id(v) {
            Some(unsafe { &*(v as *const From as *const To) })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
use sized_any::*;

use std::boxed::Box;
use std::fmt;

// `ApplyAction`

fn foreign_eq<T, U>(a: &T, b: &U) -> bool
where
    T: PartialEq + 'static,
    U: SizedAny + ?Sized + 'static,
{
    if let Some(b) = downcast_ref::<U, T>(b) {
        a == b
    } else {
        false
    }
}

pub trait ApplyAction<T: 'static>: fmt::Debug + SizedAny + 'static {
    fn foreign_eq(&self, other: &ApplyAction<T>) -> bool;
}

// requires `#![feature(specialization)]` and a nightly compiler.
// could also copy the default implementation manually to each `impl` instead.
//
// this implementation only works with sized `A` types; we cannot make 
// `ApplyAction<T>` inherit `Sized`, as that would destroy object safety.
default impl<T: 'static, A: PartialEq + 'static> ApplyAction<T> for A {
    fn foreign_eq(&self, other: &ApplyAction<T>) -> bool {
        foreign_eq(self, other)
    }
}

impl<T: 'static> PartialEq for ApplyAction<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &ApplyAction<T>) -> bool {
        self.foreign_eq(other)
    }
}

// `MyAction`

#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct MyAction<T: fmt::Debug> {
    label: T,
}

impl<T: fmt::Debug> MyAction<T> {
    pub fn new(label: T) -> MyAction<T> {
        MyAction { label: label }
    }
}

impl<T: fmt::Debug + PartialEq + 'static> ApplyAction<T> for MyAction<T> {}

// `ActionList`

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ActionList<T> {
    actions: Vec<Box<ApplyAction<T>>>,
}

impl<T: 'static> ActionList<T> {
    pub fn new() -> ActionList<T> {
        ActionList { actions: vec![] }
    }

    pub fn push<A: ApplyAction<T> + 'static>(&mut self, action: A) {
        self.actions.push(Box::<A>::new(action));
    }
}

impl<T: 'static> PartialEq for ActionList<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &ActionList<T>) -> bool {
        if self.actions.len() != other.actions.len() {
            return false;
        }
        for (i, action) in self.actions.iter().enumerate() {
            if **action != *other.actions[i] {
                return false;
            }
        }
        true
    }
}

// `main`

fn main() {
    let mut script1: ActionList<String> = ActionList::new();
    script1.push(MyAction::new("foo".to_string()));
    let mut script2: ActionList<String> = ActionList::new();
    script2.push(MyAction::new("foo".to_string()));
    let mut script3: ActionList<String> = ActionList::new();
    script3.push(MyAction::new("bar".to_string()));
    assert_eq!(script1, script2);
    assert_ne!(script1, script3);
}
```

See also:

- [Object Safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety)

Comment: Interesting, many thanks. I implemented the answer in the comment (on the question) from @red75prime, which doesn't require `Sized` or `TypeId`. It seems to work OK, except that in the "real" code I couldn't persuade Rust to derive `PartialEq` on `ActionList` automatically, but a simple manual implementation is fine. I haven't seen `specialization` before. In the real code, each `ApplyAction` struct has a method which does need to be different for each impl, can `specialization` still be used in that case?

Comment: No, if you need different code you can't use `specialization`. The example from @red75prime doesn't explicitly use `Sized`, but you probably shouldn't call `impl_comparable_for!` for unsized types.  Also it's working around the coerce `&T` into `&Any` by providing a trait method that does it (which is a fine workaround afaict).